# file pull from SFTP using python

Tags: python, sftp

```
from msilib.schema import Directory
import pysftp
import os
import glob
import fnmatch
from datetime import date, timedelta
 
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()

cnopts.hostkeys = None

myHostname = 'sftp.mmm.com'
myUsername = 'uuuu'
myPassword = 'pass'

with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    print("Connection Success")

remotefilepath='/REPORTING/test.zip'

localfilepath='Z:\\data\\sftp_data\\'

sftp.get(remotefilepath,localfilepath)
```

Hi All
I have been using above code to pull the file from SFTP and save locally
However i am getting below error

chan = t.open_session(
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'open_session'

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `with` statement ends, after the print, the connection is automatically closed.  That's what `with` is for.  Either change to a simple

```
sftp = pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts)
```

or indent the rest of the script so it's inside the `with`:

```
with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    print("Connection Success")
    remotefilepath='/REPORTING/test.zip'
    localfilepath='Z:\\data\\sftp_data\\'
    sftp.get(remotefilepath,localfilepath)
```

Comment: Thanks it work, quick one as i have modified "localfilepath= r'Z:\epay_file\sftp_data'" but still i am getting permission erro PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Z:\\epay_file\\sftp_data'

Comment: That implies that you don't have permission to write to that file share.  Are you running this as a service?

Comment: Thanks Robert for your help,i have added the file name followed by sftp_data and it worked!once again thank you